# The discrete random variable X has the probability distribution function shown below. Find $E(X).$

Tags: probability

when $x = 0$,  $ Pr[X = x] = 2/9,$

when $x = 1$, $Pr[X = x] =4/9,$

when $x = 2$    , $Pr[X = x]= 1/3$

Comment: Why not try computing using the formula $\sum_k x_k p_k$?

Answer (score 1):

$$ E(X) = 0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)$$ $$= 0+1\cdot {4\over 9}+ 2\cdot {1\over 3} = {10\over 9}$$